# Import CSV for products with new sub categories

Tags: import, magento-2.1.7

I'm importing a CSV file with new subcategories not already created.
Some times products imported correctly and others it gives me:

```
general system exception
Asymmetric transaction rollback
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: have you use re-indexing command:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: yes and flush cache and also removing var/di, var/generation

Comment: here is an article: https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error/
it might be helpfull to you

Comment: I've read it, it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and tried everything to resolve this.

- Full reset and manual reindex (completed successfully)
- Cleared Cache (cache:flush, cache:clean)
- cleared all static files
- Changed indexers to run on schedule rather than save
- Tried setting $this->_isRolledBack to false in Magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysqlphp rollback()
- Reset Server, MySql and other services.
- Tried deleting all products, reindexing and importing
- full DB restoration

From my research the issue seems to point to a DB error, so I was confident that a full DB restoration would help. But after multiple restoration I still had the issue.

During the course of creating multiple clones, and trying to import products, I was successful on one instance. The difference was I removed all the image locations in my csv. (I had a lot of images with this import) But even if I reduced my product list to 100 it would still get the error. I was successfully able to import my products and later on imported the images in a separate spreadsheet.